# Conversion of Ruby-Sourcecode to Java-Sourcecode

Tags: java, ruby, translation

I need to translate ruby-source code to java-source code. 
During my searching phase i found this website:
https://varycode.com/

The problem: 
This website is provides only this way of translation JAVA > RUBY but I need this RUBY > JAVA

Hope some one can help me otherwise I need to convert 50 classes of ruby by my own =(

Comment: Why do you need to rewrite existing code into Ruby?

Comment: You can't do this automatically, not with 100% confidence in any case. Why not use JRuby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to do this. And you can't. At least not if you expect the outcome to meet some quality standards.

If you write Java code, then write it the Java way. If you write Ruby code, then the Ruby way. 
There are lot of features that do not translate well into Java (and vice versa). While it might be easy to translate your basic "HelloWorld" example between the two languages, it becomes harder when you have stuff like

- extend/include
- classes that do not exist in Java
- meta programming
- duck typing

If you write Java directly then you can make use of stuff like method overloading, or interfaces that do not exist in ruby.

In the end it is all about writing IDIOMATIC code so you can use the full power of the language.

So you will have to bite the bullet i'd say. If you really need to translate them actually. What is the reason you want to translate the classes?

Comment: Thank you a lot. I thought already that I need to convert the logic behind the classes by my own. It is a management decision so I need to do that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to translate a small subset of Ruby into Java using [Universal-transpiler](https://jarble.github.io/transpiler/javascript/js_transpiler/test_parser.html#%7B%22inputText%22%3A%22def%20distance_formula(x1%2Cy1%2Cx2%2Cy2)%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20Math.sqrt(((x1-x2)**2)%2B((xy-y2)**2))%5Cnend%22%2C%22inputLang%22%3A%22ruby%22%2C%22outputLang%22%3A%22java%22%7D).

Given this input in Ruby:

```
def distance_formula(x1,y1,x2,y2) 
    return Math.sqrt(((x1-x2)**2)+((xy-y2)**2))
end
```

the translator will product this output in Java:

```
public static Object distance_formula(Object x1,Object y1,Object x2,Object y2){
    return Math.sqrt((Math.pow((x1-x2),2))+(Math.pow((xy-y2),2)));
}
```

Comment: that link hurts the internet

Comment: @t0il3ts0ap The link was broken, but it's fixed now.